# Conditionally chaining promises - how to avoid code duplication?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I have the following:

```
if (someCondition) {
     return promiseMakerA().then(function() {
         return promiseMakerB(someLongListOfArguments);
     });
}
else
    return promiseMakerB(someLongListOfArguments);
```

How can I eliminate that code repetition (`promiseMakerB`)?

Comment: would something like `return (someCondition ? promiseMakerA(): Promise.resolve()).then(function() {
     return promiseMakerB(someLongListOfArguments);
});` work for you?

Comment: @JaromandaX - you're on a roll.  Feel free to make an answer and I'll award - thanks so much.

Comment: Are arguments the same in each condition for promiseB? If so, can store as variable and return that variable

Comment: I'm not sure that's the **best** method, I'll wait for some other gurus to have a go :p

Comment: @charlietfl - they are - but I just tried this and I do want to avoid invoking `promiseMakerA` in the second condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do the following, however, it's not necessarily the most readable way of doing so

```
return (someCondition ? promiseMakerA(): Promise.resolve()).then(function() { 
    return promiseMakerB(someLongListOfArguments); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming arguments are the same in each condition for promiseB store it in a variable first ... then return that variable where applicable

```
let promiseB = promiseMakerB(someLongListOfArguments);

if (someCondition) {
     return promiseMakerA().then(function() {
         return promiseB;
     });
}
else
    return promiseB;
```

Comment: I like how concise Jaromanda's comment solution is - I'm using a combination.  Thank you :)